# list.append(something) unicode - ascii

Tags: python

code

```
 a = "한글" #korean language
 a_list = []
 a_list.append({'key': a})
 print a_list
```

result

```
[{'key': u'"\ud55c\uae00"'}]
```

I don't want to convert unicode.
How can I stay in korean language
I wish to print like this

```
 [{'key': '한글'}]
```

Comment: Wait, are you really asking how you can do it incorrectly?

Comment: What is the point of the dict here?  You would get the same conversion if you just had a_list = [a], wouldn't you?

Comment: You have TWO levels of quotes around your two characters worth of escape sequences. That can't have been produced by your published code. Please copy/paste, don't type from memory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code from the question produces:

```
[{'key': '\xed\x95\x9c\xea\xb8\x80'}]
```

This output is different from what you have shown in the question.

To produce: `[{"key": "한글"}]` you could use `json`:

```
print json.dumps(a_list, ensure_ascii=False, encoding=your_source_code_encoding)
```

#### Full example

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import json

a = "한글" # you should use u"" literals to work with Unicode strings
a_list = []
a_list.append({'key': a})

print json.dumps(a_list, ensure_ascii=False) # "utf-8" encoding is default
```

#### Output

```
[{"key": "한글"}]
```

You wrote:

> I dont want to convert unicode. How can I stay in korean language

Read [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html).

The main takeaway is if you are working with text you must specify its encoding.

The most convenient and reliable way is to use Unicode strings throughout your program i.e., decode bytes that you read to Unicode strings as early as possible on input and encode to bytes while writing Unicode strings as late as possible on output.

To enforce that convention all strings are Unicode in Python 3. Python 2 unfortunately allows you to use bytestrings for both text and data with all confusion that it causes.

Answer (score 1):

What difference does it make to your application if you have unicode string? If you do not want the u prefix, you could use Python3 where the strings by default are unicode.